# parsing into a struct

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

trying to parse a csv file containing lines in this format

1001,Kauri tree,1002,-1,1001,1001

and the struct node has attributes: id, name and then paths[4]     // (4 paths)
my code is not working because it seg faults. I'm on a mac so I valgrind doesn't work for me. Can anyone help with my code? or better yet give me another option for debugging? I am using the Geany IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100


typedef struct node_s {
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int paths[4];
} Node;

Node readNode(FILE *infile) 
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    Node *node = NULL;
    char* tok;
    const char comma[2] = ",";

    char* inputLine = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, infile);
    if (inputLine != NULL) {
        tok = strtok(buffer, comma);
        if (tok == NULL) {
            node->id = -1;
        } else {
            node->id = *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, comma);
            strncpy(node->name, tok, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
            int i = 0;
            while(tok != NULL || i < 4) {
                tok = strtok(NULL, comma);
                node->paths[i] = atoi(tok);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return *node;
}

int main(void) 
{
    FILE* infile = fopen("new_list.txt", "r");
    Node node = readNode(infile);
    while (node.id >= 0) {
        printf("Node: id = %d, name = '%s', neighbours = [%d, %d, %d, %d]\n",
            node.id, node.name, 
            node.paths[0], node.paths[1], node.paths[2], node.paths[3]);
        node = readNode(infile);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Node *node = NULL;`, then a few lines later: `node->id = *tok;`. `node` is still `NULL`.

Comment: In `readNode`, convert from a pointer to a struct instance (e.g. `Node node;` instead of `Node *node = NULL;`, use `node.whatever` instead of `node->whatever`, and do `return node` instead of `return *node`

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem in `readNode()` is your declaration of `Node *node = NULL;` declares a *pointer* that is initialized `NULL` and points to no valid storage. You then attempt to assign values to the memory pointed to by `node` (e.g. `NULL`) invoking *Undefined Behavior* and almost guaranteeing a SegFault.

You have several options to handle the issue,

1. *provide storage for `node` in `main()` and pass as a parameter* -- declare `node` in `main()` with automatic storage and pass the address of the struct as an additional parameter to `readNode()`, filling the values within the function (`readNode` can be declared as `void` in this case). You can also dynamically allocate `node` in `main()` and simply pass the pointer as an additional parameter,
2. *allocate storage for `node` in `readNode()` and return a pointer* -- dynamically declare storage for `node` within `readNode()` using `malloc` or `calloc` (don't forget to `free` the storage at the end of each loop to prevent a memory leak), or
3. *declare `readNode()` as type `Node`* -- the easiest way is simply to declare `node` within `readNode` and rely on the fact that a function can always return its own type to return a filled struct to `main()` as noted in the comments.

Either way will eliminate your Segmentation Fault as valid storage will be provided for `node` both in `readNode` and in `main()`.

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles. `readnode` is just a readable `readNode`, etc..

While it is perfectly fine to pass `FILE *infile` is a parameter to `readnode()`, it does you absolutely no good, and invites *Undefined Behavior* if you fail to **validate** that `infile` is open for reading before calling `readnode()` in `main()`. Library functions (and your functions should) provide a meaningful return to allow you to determine if the function call succeeded or failed -- use them, always.

Don't hard-code numbers or strings in your code (this is called using *magic numbers* -- don't do it). Instead, if you need a constant `#define` one (or more) as you have with `MAX_NAME_LENGTH` and `MAX_LINE_LENGTH`, and don't skimp on buffer sizes, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPATHS            4 
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH  64     /* don't skimp on buffer size */
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 512

typedef struct node_s {
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int paths[NPATHS];
} node_t;
```

(**note:** an exception is when numeric values are *required* in your code such as when specifying the `scanf` *field-width modifier*, etc. where a defined constant or variable is not allowed)

Reading with `fgets` is a good approach, but you need to validate that a complete line was read by checking the length against `MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1` **and** that the last character in the buffer is the newline character. Further, while parsing with `strtok` is fine, when reading *formatted input*, calling `sscanf` on the `buffer` filled by `fgets` and *validating* the number of conversions simplifies the conversion process. It is also helpful to fill a *temporary* struct with values when parsing with `sscanf` to protect against some number of members less than all being filled and rendering your `node.id >= 0` check invalid in `main()`. You could do something like the following:

```
node_t readnode (FILE *infile) 
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    node_t node = {.id = -1};   /* initialize node to indicate error */

    if (fgets (buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, infile)) {  /* validate line read */
        node_t tmp = {.id = 0};         /* parse to temporary node */
        size_t len = strlen (buffer);   /* get length */
        /* validate complete line read */
        if (len == MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1 && buffer[len-1] != '\n') {
            /* handle line too long */
            fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
            /* discard remaining characters in line */
            while (fgets (buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, infile)) {
                len = strlen (buffer);
                if (len && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
                    break;
            }
        }
        /* parse csv values using sscanf, validate return */
        if (sscanf (buffer, "%d,%64[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d", &tmp.id, tmp.name,
                    &tmp.paths[0], &tmp.paths[1], &tmp.paths[2], 
                    &tmp.paths[3]) == 6)
            node = tmp;     /* good parse, assign tmp to node */
        else    /* parse failed, issue error, return zeroed node */
            fputs ("readnode() error: parse of line failed.\n", stderr);
    }

    return node;  /* return filled node on success, zeroed node otherwise */
}
```

Putting all the pieces together in a short example based on your code, you could do something similar to to the following that will read from the filename provided as the first-argument to your program (or from `stdin` by default if no argument is given):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPATHS            4 
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH  64     /* don't skimp on buffer size */
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 512

typedef struct node_s {
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int paths[NPATHS];
} node_t;

node_t readnode (FILE *infile) 
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    node_t node = {.id = -1};   /* initialize node to indicate error */

    if (fgets (buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, infile)) {  /* validate line read */
        node_t tmp = {.id = 0};         /* parse to temporary node */
        size_t len = strlen (buffer);   /* get length */
        /* validate complete line read */
        if (len == MAX_LINE_LENGTH - 1 && buffer[len-1] != '\n') {
            /* handle line too long */
            fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
            /* discard remaining characters in line */
            while (fgets (buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, infile)) {
                len = strlen (buffer);
                if (len && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
                    break;
            }
        }
        /* parse csv values using sscanf, validate return */
        if (sscanf (buffer, "%d,%64[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d", &tmp.id, tmp.name,
                    &tmp.paths[0], &tmp.paths[1], &tmp.paths[2], 
                    &tmp.paths[3]) == 6)
            node = tmp;     /* good parse, assign tmp to node */
        else    /* parse failed, issue error, return zeroed node */
            fputs ("readnode() error: parse of line failed.\n", stderr);
    }

    return node;  /* return filled node on success, zeroed node otherwise */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    node_t node = {.id = 0};
    FILE *infile = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    /* validate file open for reading */
    if (infile == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-infile");
        return 1;
    }

    node = readnode (infile);   /* struct can be assigned */

    while (node.id >= 0) {
        printf ("Node: id = %4d, name = '%s',%*s"
                "neighbours = [%d, % 4d, %d, %d]\n",
                node.id, node.name, 11 - (int)strlen(node.name), " ", 
                node.paths[0], node.paths[1], node.paths[2], node.paths[3]);
        node = readnode (infile);
    }

    if (infile != stdin) fclose (infile);   /* if not stdin, close file */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/struct_node.csv
1001,Kauri tree,1002,-1,1001,1001
1002,Beach tree,1003,-2,1002,1002
1003,Pine tree,1004,-10,1003,1003
1004,Elm tree,1005,-100,1004,1004
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_rd_csv_node <dat/struct_node.csv
Node: id = 1001, name = 'Kauri tree', neighbours = [1002,   -1, 1001, 1001]
Node: id = 1002, name = 'Beach tree', neighbours = [1003,   -2, 1002, 1002]
Node: id = 1003, name = 'Pine tree',  neighbours = [1004,  -10, 1003, 1003]
Node: id = 1004, name = 'Elm tree',   neighbours = [1005, -100, 1004, 1004]
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.